# Drupal 9 administration interface accidentally changed

Tags: drupal, interface, themes, administration, appearance

Hello to everyone and thanks in advance,

I accidentally changed the administration pages interface, I will attach an image for everyone to see. Is it possible to go back to default interface??
[new interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElpZk.png)
[old interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFYKb.png)
Thank you,

George

I tried going to theme settings but did not find an option

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/admin/appearance`

Check for the dropdown button on the "Administration Theme" Section.
Update (with the old one) and save it.

If you can't find it, you can set it by using drush.

As I could check from the screenshot, the admin theme you need to switch back seems to be 'claro'.

You can also use drush to update it. Here it goes:

```
drush theme:enable claro
drush config-set system.theme admin claro
drush cr
```

If you don't know what theme to enable, you can list'em by typing

```
drus pm-list --type=theme
```